# Find width of a tab item? (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, winapi

I want to be able to know how much room a particular tab takes up, is there a way to calculate this knowing it's text and having its item struct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a SysTabControl how about [`TCM_GETITEMRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760594%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?